# Performance tuning in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to do performance tuning for a SQL Server table to speed up the inserts?

For example in an `Employee` table I have 150 000 records. When I am trying to insert a few more records (around 20k), it is taking 10-15 minutes.

Comment: How are you inserting the records? Row-by-row?

Answer (score 1):

Performance tuning using wait stats is a good approach in your case..below are few steps i would do

**step1:**
Run insert query

**step2:**
open another session and run below

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests
```

Now status and wait type column should give you enough info on what are your next steps

**Ex:**
  If status is blocked(normally inserts won't be blocked),check the blocking query and see why it is blocked

Above is just an example and there is more info online for any wait type you might encounter

Comment: Thanks Thegameiswar.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for speeding inserts is to do a bulk insert into a temporary table and then a single insert into the final table.

This assumes that the source of the new records is an external file.

In any case, your question leaves lots of important information unexplained:

- How are you doing the inserts now?  It should not be taking 10-15 minutes to insert 20k records.
- How many indexes are on the table?
- How large is each record?
- What triggers are on the table?
- What other operations are taking place on the server?
- What is the source of the records being inserted?
- Do you have indexed views that use the table?

There are many reasons why inserts could be slow.

Comment: Thanks gordon.records are inserted thru dataload and some times from one table to main employee table. . Only one index there.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas in addition to checking for locks

Disable any on insert triggers if They exist and incorporate there logic into your insert. Also disable any indexes on table and reenable post bulk insert.